# sudo -H with curly brackets

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I saw at lodash.com this install snippet:

```
$ {sudo -H} npm i -g npm
```

Why are there curly brackets?

Where is the difference between:

```
$ sudo -H npm i -g npm
```

Thanks!

Comment: your first example doesn't work for reasons that Emil Kakkau's man page excerpt explains.  There must be whitespace around the braces and the list of commands must end with a semicolon

Comment: It is a sample of the installation of lodash. 

Source: https://lodash.com/?v3

Comment: arrrgh. it has nothing to do with bash. in that context it just means use `npm` with `sudo -H` if you are not root already. this prefix is just optional here.

Comment: the usage depends on the location where you install your node.js packages. if they are placed in a user directory then you possibly do not need the `sudo -H` prefix. hope that helps.

Comment: ok, but is there a difference between:

{sudo -H} npm i -g npm 

and 

sudo -H npm i -g npm

??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** have a look at the comments of your question. it is not bash related.

an extract of the bash man page. hope this helps.

> { list; }
>
> ```
>          list is simply executed in the current shell environment.   list
>          must  be  terminated with a newline or semicolon.  This is known
>          as a group command.  The return status is  the  exit  status  of
>          list.   Note that unlike the metacharacters ( and ), { and } are
>          reserved words and must occur where a reserved word is permitted
>          to  be  recognized.   Since they do not cause a word break, they
>          must be separated from  list  by  whitespace  or  another  shell
>          metacharacter.
> ```

Comment: not realy! I read the manpage already. But {sudo -H} is only one command with an option, so why i need to write this in curly brackets?

Comment: check bracket expansion as well. perhaps it just expands to `sudo -H` in fact it is an option. is this command working with brackets? tried with other commands but none of them worked when using those brackets.

Comment: when regarding bracket expansion something like `ls /bin/{date}` will work. but without any context it is hard to say how `{ sudo -H }` is interpreted if it is.